# Keypress event for dynamically created winform in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, keypress

I'm creating a windows form at run-time. Now i want the Key-press event to be triggered for the dynamically created form.
How do i create/bind the event to newly/dynamically created windows form in C#.

Thanks,

Comment: which type of control key press?

Comment: like "Ctrl + C" or "Ctrl + V"

Comment: You can find examples about how to handle key presses by looking at the answers by Seminda or Shujaat. More documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

If we take a text box its like this.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox myTextBox = new TextBox();
        myTextBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(myTextBox_KeyPress);

        this.Controls.Add(myTextBox);
    }

    void myTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Key press event work here
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Make sure that the focus should be on `Form2`.

Comment: tried same code.. but still event is not triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Try This.

```
Form dynamicForm = new Form();

dynamicForm.KeyPress += new KeyEventHandler(onkeyPress);    


 void onkeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
 }
```

Comment: tried same code.. but still event is not triggered. On tab control, the dynamically generated form is placed. Even tried the keypress event for the tab control... but still same..

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the forms [KeyPreview Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) is set to true, that way it will see the keystrokes.

From above link:

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress, KeyDown, and KeyUp events. After the form's event handlers have completed processing the keystroke, the keystroke is then assigned to the control with focus. For example, if the KeyPreview property is set to true and the currently selected control is a TextBox, after the keystroke is handled by the event handlers of the form the TextBox control will receive the key that was pressed. To handle keyboard events only at the form level and not allow controls to receive keyboard events, set the KeyPressEventArgs.Handled property in your form's KeyPress event handler to true.

So you will want to do something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 f2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyPreview = true;
        KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
    }

    void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Control)
        {
            switch(e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.C:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cntrl C");
                    break;
                case Keys.V:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cntrl V");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: even after KeyPreview Property is set to true.. still the same isse.. exists.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is then without seeing how you are implementing it. The code I gave you is working code